# User login "log" on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, login, logging

Does Mac OS record user logins/logouts?

I'm in a situation where I need to show that a certain user was logged in at a certain time (long story) less than four weeks ago.

Is this recorded at the Mac OS level or Darwin level anywhere?

EDIT:
The machine is running Mac OS Leopard (non-server edition).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try the command `last` which unless the log has been cleared should have a log right back until the OS was installed. Specifically look for any console entries.

Comment: Sweet! I was right, to. Even sweeter.

Comment: This is for shutdown, reboots. How about "lock screens" logins, there is something similar?

Comment: How to check for lock screen logins?

Answer (score 10):

If you want to look back further than the few weeks that `last` will show these entries are stored for much longer in the ASL database. To view logins use this command, substituting the name you are searching for, or leave off the `| grep insert_username_here` to see everyone.

```
syslog -F raw -k Facility com.apple.system.lastlog | grep insert_username_here
```

To see logouts use:

```
syslog -F raw -k Facility com.apple.system.utmpx | grep insert_username_here
```

To view this more cleanly you could use this, which does not show logins via terminal and will show just the epoch times. You must grep for a username or else the data is meaningless:

```
syslog -F raw -k Facility com.apple.system.lastlog | grep insert_username_here | grep -v tty | awk '{ print $2 }' | sed -e 's/]//g'
```

The date is displayed as the epoch time. You can convert that to normal time with http://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. FYI I was after "GUI" logins, so this should do the trick as well.